# How do I use the volume-indicator callback event with AngularAgoraRtcService?

Tags: angular, agora.io

Here(https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#enableaudiovolumeindicator) is the option I am trying to implement. However my client object which comes from the AngularAgoraRtcService does not have this 'enableaudiovolumeindicator' property, how do I trigger this event? or how can I manually set up an event that triggers ever second like it does?

Answer (score 0):

The `AngularAgoraRtcService` is an outdated Angular wrapper, it is not an up to date and is not a full implementation of the Agora Web SDK. I would recommend using the [ngx-agora](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-agora) package.

The `ngx-agora` package includes the [enableAudioVolumeIndicator](https://github.com/drew-thompson/ngx-agora/blob/cd075d7a61fb84df6182361d450622868a75bde4/projects/ngx-agora/src/lib/data/models/agora-client.model.ts#L117) and the [volume-indicator](https://github.com/drew-thompson/ngx-agora/blob/cd075d7a61fb84df6182361d450622868a75bde4/projects/ngx-agora/src/lib/data/enums/client-event.enum.ts#L171) callback event.